# Adding corresponding column A values if values in column B match one another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, sumifs

I need to create a formula that adds up column A if the values in column B match.

```
A          B          
1        123    
1        123       
2        345       
2        345    
1        345
```

So for this example I need it to add up `123`'s to show `2` and `345`'s to show `5`. I have been playing with SUMIF and VLOOKUP but haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In row2 and copied down to suit:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,B2,A:A)
```